# Kivy: ScreenManager() para Limpar Widgets antes da transição de tela

Tags: python, python-kivy, kivy

Estou construindo uma aplicação com Python e Kivy.

Para alternar as telas uso o 'ScreenManager' do Kivy. Ex.:

```
Button:
    text: 'Sair de Tela 2 e voltar para Tela 1'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 100
    on_press: root.manager.current = 'tela1'
```

Porém, na Tela 2 adiciono e excluo itens de uma lista, entre outras coisas que alteram o layout da tela.
E preciso que ao sair desta tela, tudo seja limpo/zerado, para que quando voltar a tela esteja limpar e também para isso não sobrecarregar a aplicação com itens desnecessários salvos no layout.

Conheço o método **self.clear_widgets()**,
**Mas gostaria de saber se o ScreenManager() tem alguma propriedade ou método que faça isso?**
Porque se eu tiver que criar uma função que faça a transição de tela, usando o clear_widgets() para limpar a tela... creio que fica inviável continuar com o ScreenManager()

Comment: existe o método `root.manager.clear_widgets()`

Answer (score 1):

Oi, você pode usar para remover os widgtes de uma tela utilizando a função `remove_widget()`. Como a sua tela pode ter widgtes filhos (widgets que estão dentro dela) você pode removê-los usando o atributo children da sua tela.

No seguinte código tenho uma tela e quando sair dela todos os widgets dela serão remividos:

```
class Tela(Screen):
     def on_pre_leave(self):
         #Função para configurar eventos antes de sair
         for widget in range(len(self.children)):
          #Estrutura de repetição para contar os seus 
          #widgets filhos e transforma-los em uma lista
               self.remove_widget(self.children[0])
          #Função que remove o widget filho na posição 0
          #a cada volta, um widget com índice maior torna-se 
          #o primeiro(0) e é removido
```